# Creating a program to write and read a text file w/menu [Python3.x]

Tags: python-3.x, function, variables, while-loop, boolean

This is my first *program*... sort of. Basically what I'm trying to do is a text-based menu and a program that can read and write to a text file.

```
f = open("base.txt", "a+")
read_base = open("base.txt", "r")

backno = "N"
backyes = "Y"
interface = True


def user_input(name):
if menu == 1:
    f.write(name + "\n")


while interface:
print("1.Add a name to the base\n2.Delete a name from the base\n3.Get name from the base\n4.Edit a name\n5.Exit")
menu = int(input("Input an option: "))
if menu == 1:
    user_input(name=input("Type a name: "))
    name_added()
elif menu == 2:
    print("\nOption 2 executed")
elif menu == 3:
    print("\nOption 3 executed")
elif menu == 4:
    print("\nOption 4 executed")
elif menu > 4:
    print("Program closed")
    interface = False
```

This is the approach that I came up with to do a menu. I want the menu to close if one option is exectued and the user wants to exit. So I wrote this

```
def name_added():
print("\nName added\n")
print("\nBack to menu?\n""\nY[  ]N[  ]")
backmen = input("")
if backmen == "Y":
  interface = True
elif backmen == "N":
  interface = False
```

The problem is that the function name_added does not recognize *interface* as a variable and therefore it does not change it's value

Answer (score 0):

The `name_added` is creating a local variable when setting `interface`. To tell python to reference the global `interface` variable, use the `global` call.

Try this code:

```
def name_added():
    global interface  #  <<< add this line
    print("\nName added\n")
    print("\nBack to menu?\n""\nY[  ]N[  ]")
    backmen = input("")
    if backmen == "Y":
      interface = True
    elif backmen == "N":
      interface = False
```

You can also have the function return the interface result:

```
def name_added():
    global interface  #  <<< add this line
    print("\nName added\n")
    print("\nBack to menu?\n""\nY[  ]N[  ]")
    backmen = input("")
    if backmen == "Y":
      return True
    elif backmen == "N":
      return False

while interface:
    .....
    if menu == 1:
        user_input(name=input("Type a name: "))
        interface = name_added()   # returned value
    ......
```